# input type range doesn't initialize value

Tags: angularjs

I'm having trouble getting the input to initialize a value

View:

```
<form ng-submit="changeDistance(form)" id="form">
  <input min="1" max="50" ng-model="form.distance" type="range"> 
  <button type="submit" >
  Done
  </button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.form = {};
$scope.form.distance = $localStorage.distance;

$scope.changeDistance = function(form){
 $localStorage.distance = form.distance;
}
```

---

This works but problem is value can't be submitted:

```
View:

    <form ng-submit="changeDistance(form)" id="form">
      <input min="1" max="50" ng-model="distance" type="range"> 
      <button type="submit" >
      Done
      </button>
    </form>

Controller:


    $scope.distance = $localStorage.distance;

    $scope.changeDistance = function(form){
     console.log(form.distance)//cannot read
    }
```

Comment: Did you check your localStorage?! Isn't `distance` Undefined?

Comment: @soroushgholamzadeh distance is defined when you do console.log(form.distance) only issue is initializing the value.. submitting has no problem

Answer (score 0):

This is a confirmed bug for Angular 1.2.  See the [Github bug report](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6726) for more details.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Your'e right, But there is no essential part in the link, just using custom directives or reporting if issue solved or not, Any way if you think it's wrong I'll remove it

Comment: I edited your answer to make it more obvious that this is a bug within angular itself.  That way the link is a nice reference, but not necessary for the core information.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Thank you so much, I got it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try your above code (where you're using `ng-model="form.distance"`) with angular 1.3.14 and above.

http://codepen.io/zrdesign/pen/jPRjeM